# How to avoid overlap of markers

Tags: openstreetmap, cloudmade

I've a lot markers inside of a cloudemade map. Sometimes there is a number ob markers at the same location. I use the cluster functionallity but how can I avoid that there are more then one marker on the same coordinats? In such a case, I simply want to have the marker beside each other.

```
var myMarkerLatLng = new CM.LatLng(<?php echo($rowg['lat'].','.$rowg['lon']); ?>);
                var myMarker = new CM.Marker(myMarkerLatLng, {
                    title: "<?php echo($row['name']); ?>",
                    icon: icon 
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Our old Web Maps API is deprecated. Please use Leaflet instead of it. You can find good code examples here http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html. Is is free and easy customisable.